# Yii: can't use LIMIT in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, limit

I'm using Yii, and I want to select 5 rows from mysql starting from the third row.

For Example, I have these rows:

```
ID - NAME
1  - abc
2  - bcd
3  - hdf
4  - fgr
5  - gdf
...
```

and I want to select 5 rows, starting from the third row.

My code:

```
$rows = Users::model()->findAll(array(
    'order' => 'id DESC',
    'limit' => '3, 5'
));
```

The problem this selects nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an offset parameter.

```
$rows = Users::model()->findAll(array(
  'order' => 'id DESC',
  'limit' => '5',
  'offset' => '3'
));
```